# How to factor this algebraic identity used in Lagrange's theorem for polynomial congruences

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, modular-arithmetic, factoring

The question is how to factor an identity.  The identity is shown below but it uses $f(x)$ as defined in Theorem 5.21, so let me show $f$'s definition first.

[image: def of f(x)]

In the proof, we eventually get to this identity:

[image: algebraic identity]

We have two equations there.  I'm good with the first.  Just expanding it out makes it obvious.  My problem is on the second equation.  By taking the expansion and factoring $x$ on all non-$x_0$ terms, I get

$$x(c_n x^{n-1} + \cdots + c_2 x + c_1).$$

Similarly for $x_0$,

$$x_0(c_n x_0^{n-1} + \cdots + c_2 x_0 + c_1).$$

**Question**.  How can I use these two expressions and get the second equation in the identity?

If I let $g(x) = (c_n x^{n-1} + \cdots + c_2 x + c_1)$, then I have $g(x)$ in the first expression above and $g(x_0)$ in the second.  These are not the same, so I'm puzzled as how this is allowed.

Comment: Use that $a^k - b^k = (a-b)(a^{k-1}+a^{k-2}b+\cdots+ab^{k-2}+b^{k-1})$.

Comment: By the linked Factor Theorem  $\,x-x_0\mid x^r-x_0^r$ so $\,x-x_0\,$ divides each summand hence it divides the entire sum, which yields the [general Factor Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/738715/242) $\,x-a\mid f(x)-f(a).\ $ [Generally](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2049882/242) a nonzero polynomial over a domain has no more roots than its degree.